# How to navigate websites using Jsoup in java

Tags: java, html-parsing, web-crawler, jsoup

How can i navigate (like web crawling) in Jsoup to a different link?

For this example I have done the basics to get the title, get links and get texts. But I want to be able to use one of those child links and go to the inside of that child link.

For example from google web page I want to be able to go to youtube page because its one of the child links in google and once in youtube pick another child link and than be able to grab a string.

How would I be able to do this in Jsoup?

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class JSoupTest {


public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {


        Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get();

        // get page title
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println(title);

        //gets all links
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {

        // get the value from href attribute
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));

        }

        for( Element element : doc.select("p") )    
                    // Select all 'p'-Tags and loop over them
        {
            if( element.hasText() )                 
                    // Check if the element has text (since there are some empty too)
            {
              System.out.println(element.text()); // print the element's text
            }
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch that page i.e.

```
String link_addr = link.attr("href");
Document link_doc = Jsoup.connect(link_addr).get();
// do stuff with link_doc
```

If you're processing lots of children pages of the same type you probably want to make a helper method to do this i.e.

```
public void do_stuff_with(String link_addr){
  String link_addr = link.attr("href");
  Document link_doc = Jsoup.connect(link_addr).get();
  // do stuff with link_doc
}
```

Comment: If I use Jsoup to navigate thru the different child links, and some of the links are generated by javascript can i still navigate thru them? or that will be a problem

Comment: If you can extract the links from the html you can use them. Do you have an example (page) that you have in mind?

Comment: An example would be go to http://www.w3schools.com/  main page than use the link "Learn SQL" (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) In the Learn SQL page I want to go to the link "Start learning SQL now!" (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp)  so in general I would  1.) connect to an URL, 2.) parse the informations I need, 3.) select all further links, 4.) connect to them and 5.) continue this as long as there are new links.

Comment: Yep, exactly. How you structure it will depend on what "parse the information" means i.e. if it's different or the same at each level, if the page layout is genuinely recursive. Some dynamic content can be difficult to work with but that page looks straightforward.

Comment: I hate to ask but would you be able to show me using my code how would i add the code you posted I was already able to select all the links from the first page now i want to select all further links. Thank you!